# NullReferenceException on if statement with only a bool check

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nullreferenceexception

I'm experiencing a "strange" situation with a live ASP.NET MVC 3 app. The error start on production after X hours of use. I did not have been able to reproduce the error on my development machine.

Here is my controller action signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddBanking(int id, int? page, int bankId, 
    string q, int? searchFlag, string query, string accountNo, 
    string accountManager, bool? personnal, int? branchId, 
    int? selectedId, BankSearchModel data)
```

The basic idea is that the controller is use for two forms on the View, one for searching where searchFlag is a Hidden field and another form for adding, here is a basic code structure.

```
try
{
  if (searchFlag.HasValue)
  {
    var vm = svc.FetchBanks(bankId, q);

    return View(vm);
  }
  else
  {
     bool valid = true, isIndividu = false;

     // some code

     if(!valid) // <- this is where the line 106 is 
     {
     }
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  ex.Data.Add("context", "AddBanking - THIS IS IT");
  Log.Error(ex);
  return RedirectToAction("Error", new { id = 0 });
}
```

The error occurs after long periods of time the app run flawlessly, all of a sudden, that exception is caught, but when the users submit the first form (for searching -> searchFlag = 1), so in my example it entered the first if statement.

This is the error and stack trace

```
context: AddBanking - THIS IS IT

    Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Stack:
      at XYZ.Controllers.BanksController.AddBanking(Int32 id, Nullable`1 page, Int32
 bankId, String q, Nullable`1 searchFlag, String query, String accountNo, String 
accountManager, Nullable`1 personnal, Nullable`1 branchId, Nullable`1 selectedId, 
BankSearchModel data) in E:\Projects\XYZ\ABC\123.Web\Controllers\BanksController.cs:line 
106
```

1. How can it be possible to throw exception on a if statement with a non-nullable bool ?
2. Since there is a return View() in my first if block, and I'm 100 % certain it entered there how come the exception is on the line 106 where the execution should not even go there.
3. This is something that happen only after long period of production time, yesterday (8 to 5) this process worked, and this morning bang the exception is throwing, but only in production (Windows 2008, ASP.NET MVC 3). From my developement machine with the same database and same data posting to the page is working.

My main question, how am I suppose to debug this, at first I thought that the stack trace does not returned the right line number, so I added a try/catch inside the action, yet it still return the if(!valid) as NRE...

I would appreciate any idea / guide line. Of course I could separate the two process inside the action and it might fix the problem, but I would rather like to understand what I'm doing wrong in the example.

**Edit: I'm completely clueless**
By the time I asked this question, the page worked without any change in code and for the exact same data posted.

**Edit 2 @ 10:30 2011/06/01**

Thanks for your suggestions, but I'm really thinking this is really something harder to find. The bug did re-appear today but the app was working from 1 hour after I post this question yesturday until today @ 10 am.

Here is more detail on what I've done so far to try to understand what's going on:

1. I've rebuilt the app (no code changes, and re-deploy bin, views) with .pdb files.
2. I've put try/catch on every path that the execution should take here is the exact scenario:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary()

  <fieldset>
  @Html.Hidden("searchFlag", 1)
  @Html.Textbox("q")
  <input type="submit" value="Chercher" /></td>
  </fieldset>
}
```

**svc cannot be null** because I have it set on the controller like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class BanksController : BaseController
{
  BankService svc = new BankService();
  ...
}
```

The FetchBanks method

```
public BankSearchModel FetchBanks(int bankId, string query)
{
  return Execute<BankSearchModel>(db =>
  {
    try
    {
      // some linq stuff
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      XYZ.Log.Error(ex); // <= note1
  }, "Error returned by Execute");
}
```

My Execute method

```
protected static T Execute<T>(Func<XYZDbContext, T> query, string errorMessage, bool deferredLoading)
{
  try
  {
    using (XYZDbContext db = new XYZ...())
    {
#if DEBUG
      db.Log = new DebuggerWriter();
      db.CommandTimeout = 3 * 60;
#endif
      if (!deferredLoading)
        db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

      return query(db);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
#if DEBUG
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    throw;
#else
    ex.Data.Add("context", "Manager, executing query");
    XYZ.Log.Error(ex); 
    return default(T);
#endif
  }
}
```

So again, I understand that the line 106 is not the real error here, but I have try/cath in every single method that the execution should go when the searchFlag is set to 1 (from the first form of the view. Still the only Log.Error(ex) I got was the one telling me there is an error on my contorller at line 106.

**Note1** If the error would have come from the FetchBanks method it would have entered the catch inside that method and send me and email with stack trace of that method.

At the end of my FetchBanks I return a BankSearchModel which as all List so all databases query are executed before returning to the controller.

**And again, how can it work for the same data posted all day long and suddently stop working**. Would that be possible that the signature of the controller with all my null object would cause that behaviour?

This is the only email I got after adding try/catch everywhere that should have send me an error. i.e no other method are entering their catch (The execute, the FetchBanks) only the controller action. I would really like to understand what's going on.

```
New error occured at 6/1/2011 9:48:13 AM

context: AddBanking - THIS IS IT

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack:
  at XYZ.Web.Controllers.BanksController.AddBanking(Int32 id, Nullable`1 page, Int32
```

bankId, String q, Nullable`1 searchFlag, String query, String accountNo, String 
accountManager, Nullable`1 personnal, Nullable`1 branchId, Nullable`1 selectedId, 
BankSearchModel data) in 
E:\Projects\HiddenForObiousReason\Controllers\BanksController.cs:line 106

Comment: Clearly, the exception is not being thrown from that if statement. You probably have a mismatch between the source and the binaries or the PDB files. Rebuild the application (in DEBUG configuration), redeploy and hopefully reproduce. Be sure to include the .PDB files.

Comment: The PDB are already on the server, but I'm deploying with the Release mode. I understand that this line "could" be the one throwing the exception: var vm = svc.FetchBanks(bankId, q); but I have a try/catch in that method "FetchBanks" that should had log any exception if it was that...

Comment: As John mentioned, it seems that CLR is confused and reports incorrect line numbers. Rebuild your solution (Clean/RebuildAll) and try again. It happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After separating my action into two disctinct action (for the two forms in the view) I discover that the errors was relating to the second form and related to the validation of the Model passed.

Here are my two actions now:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddBanking(int id, int? page, int bankId, string q)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateBanking(int id, int? page, int bankId, string query, string 
accountNo, string accountManager, bool? personnal,
int? branchId, int? selectedId, BankSearchModel data)
```

The error was thrown when the first form was posted, but the Html.ValidationSummary was not writing any errors to the view. After separating the action no error were thrown on the first form, but only on the second and now the ValidationSummary is writing to the View. That is normal and I understand that the first form now do not validate the Model.

What I still cannot fully understand exactly why the error was raising on batch of 15 minutes once a day (from 8am to 5pm). If someone has explanation I would appreciate it. Why a form post with the exact same data works and later do not work (the two posts were supposed to fail since the Model Validation was the cause of the error).

That was probably my mistake to have 1 action for two distinct functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, check the objects for null.

I wouldn't worry about line 106 so much, check the object(s) in the code for null.

Example:

```
if (svc == null)
{
    Log.Error(new Exception("svc is null!"); 
}
```

You have lots of strings in that method call, strings default to null if they are unassigned, so that could be a source of the error as well.

Comment: The svc cannot be null, it is instantiated as a protected variable on the Controller class. (poor man's DI). As for the null string, the only string that is use in the first if is the "q" and I saw the user entering a string and getting the error via SharedView. Since there is a return View in the first if, I would think that the else block are not evaluated? And yes I'm sure it entered the if statment. This code work almost 22 hour / day. After my SharedView session while I was writing the question here, I retest with the exact same data "q" as the user, and it worked (no rebuid, no deploy)

Comment: If the error is a mystery, I would still add additional debugging/tracing in this method to see the contents of the variables.   You could do this in the catch to avoid a performance hit and have it call another method to write out all the variables and also test each variable to null to see which one is throwing the null refrence exception.  then once the problem is solved, take out the additionally logging in the exception.  I think that is your best bet going forward to solve the mystery.